# How to update parent class property so it would be available for existing child class instances

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a multiple instances of the classes that have the same parent class. And for specific case it is required to update parent class property so all available instances of the child classes would access updated property.

I can reach it with `prototype` in case if class property doesn't exist already:

```
class Foo {
    someVal = 'Hello'
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

let inst = new Bar()
Foo.prototype.someNewValue = 'Hello World'
console.log(inst.someNewValue) //Hello World
```

But in my case I need to update an already existing property:

```
class Foo {
    someVal = 'Hello'
}

class Bar extends Foo {

}

let inst = new Bar()
Foo.prototype.someVal= 'Hello World'
console.log(inst.someVal) //Still output "Hello" because existing property value has a more priority than a value from prototype. While "Hello World" is desirable
```

Comment: I think the class field `someVal` doesn't exist on the prototype, but is instead defined in the constructor.

Comment: What you are describing you want is NOT an instance variable or property.  It's a class static property (one value available to all instances).  It sounds like you should change the property to be a class static and change how you access it to refer to the class static.  Class instance properties are unique to each instance of the class and thus have independent values.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you. With some code modification it solves my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

With the `prototype`, you can not overwrite and change the property of class, but you can set the new property to the class
try this:

```
  class Foo {}
    
  class Bar extends Foo {}
    
  let inst = new Bar();
  Foo.prototype.someVal = "Hello World";
  console.log(inst.someVal);
  //hello world
```